# How to apply trasform rotation at global space in Unity5?

Tags: blender, gameobject, unity-game-engine

When you use Blender to apply rotation as well as Unity3d: If you do it using the transform properties doesn't matter if you are on Global space or Local space, you get the same result. 
But in Blender you're allowed to apply rotations specifying for each axis the Global or Local space, so you can get what you want (not in the transform properties box, but with hotkeys). 
**How do you get this on Unity3d?**

(In fact in Blender you can do this with more than one object selected)
Thank you in advance.

[image: Rotating 2 items in Blender in the global space]

[image: Rotating 2 items in Blender in the local space]

[image: Rotating a GameObject on an axis parallel to the isometric view, after restarting the rotation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the winner is.....
Irwiss with this amazing tip

**Irwess said at IRC:**

> The local/global switch only affects the gizmos in scene view,
>   inspector will local transform values, since doing global would make
>   it lose precision.

Comment: Amazing! Here I am editing a poorly worded old question ... and the disinterested user did not arrive late to gave negative feedback. 
If at any time you have a question that only a handful can answer, I hope you have a blackout! (A very long one)